# %DOCUMENTS% environment variable does not work in App.config file of a WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, environment-variables, serilog, serilog-sinks-file

I have a WPF application and want to use Serilog to log context in a local txt file. I have installed **Serilog**, **Serilog.Sinks.File** and **Serilog.Settings.AppSettings** packages.

After launching and terminating the tool, I fail to find the txt file in the folder. I guess I set the path value using wrong environment variable. Can someone helps me to correct?

In the App class in App.xaml.cs file, I add following code in the constructor App().

```
Log.Logger=new LoggerConfiguration().ReadFrom.AppSettings().CreateLogger();
Log.Information("##########################################################");
Log.Information("############## Tool started...###############");
Log.Information("##########################################################");
```

In the App.config file I add following key-value pairs to set logger.

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="serilog:minimum-level" value="Verbose" />
  <add key="serilog:using:File" value="Serilog.Sinks.File" />
  <add key="serilog:write-to:File.path" value="%DOCUMENTS%\Logs\Tool-.txt" />
  <add key="serilog:write-to:File.rollingInterval" value="Day" />
  <add key="serilog:write-to:File.retainedFileCountLimit" value="10" />
</appSettings>
```

**Update:**

I changed the value to `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\ESI_Effort_A350\Logs\ESIA350-.txt` and it works now. Seems this to be a solution. But is there a direct environment varibale for Documents folder?

Comment: If you create such an Environment Variable yes but there isn't a predefined standard one. Is it an option to do in code configuration so you get access to the SpecialFolders API instead of using a config file?

Comment: @Ralf Thank you for letting me know there is no predefined one for Documents folder. I know I can do that in code but this time I am researching if I can put them in AppConfig file.

Comment: Since its app specific data maybe an easy solution (and more appropriate) is to store that in APPDATA or LOCALAPPDATA.

Comment: start a prompt, use `env` to dump what's available, pick the best one (the google to verify what versions you can expect it to be present for reliably)

Comment: Look at [Default Known Folders in Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/knownfolderid). You'll find `FOLDERID_Documents` with default path `%USERPROFILE%\Documents`. So your solution is correct and does not need further improvement. To get a list of all environment variables, the command is `set`, not `env`.

Comment: The following may be of interest: [Environment.SpecialFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=net-8.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But is there a direct environment variable for the Documents folder?

This should work in C#:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
```

In configuration, `%USERPROFILE%\Documents` should work just fine. `%DOCUMENTS%` is invalid.